# Why isn't my Elmah configuration being applied?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, elmah, elmah.mvc

I've inherited a legacy internal site written using ASP.NET MVC. It uses Elmah to mail uncaught exceptions. Unfortunately, those emails contain sensitive information, such as passwords. Following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24914392/713735), I implemented this `ErrorLogModule` class to remove sensitive fields from the error reports:

```cs
using Elmah;
using System.Linq;
using ElmahErrorLogModule = Elmah.ErrorLogModule;

namespace HRCommittee
{
    // method taken and modified from https://stackoverflow.com/a/24914392/713735
    public class ErrorLogModule : ElmahErrorLogModule
    {
        protected override void OnErrorSignaled(object sender, ErrorSignalEventArgs args)
        {
            string[] serverVariables = args.Context.Request.ServerVariables.AllKeys;
            string[] varsToRemove = { "AUTH_PASSWORD", "HTTP_COOKIE", "ALL_HTTP", "ALL_RAW" };

            if (serverVariables != null)
            {
                foreach (string var in varsToRemove)
                {
                    if (serverVariables.Contains(var))
                    {
                        args.Context.Request.ServerVariables.Remove(var);
                    }
                }
            }

            base.OnErrorSignaled(sender, args);
        }
    }
}
```

However, the emails are unchanged. Furthermore, after implementing the above code, I saw that someone else had placed a file identical to the guide I linked in another location, but also without success. Since Elmah is pretty much undocumented, and I'm quite new to the Microsoft stack, I've been struggling to figure out what's wrong.

By the way, the relevant entries in `web.config` tell a bit of the story of what has been tried:

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <!--<add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />-->
      <!--<add name="ErrorLog" type="HRCommittee.App_Start.ErrorLogModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />-->
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="HRCommittee.ErrorLogModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <!-- other stuff -->
</system.webServer>
```

What am I missing?

## Update

I've set up a local SMTP server, run the site locally, and triggered an exception thus (copying existing code in the project):

```cs
try
{
    throw new Exception("Test message");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    AccountController.LogToElmah("Error Saving Form", e);
}
```

In this case, the emails are redacted as expected. I tried it with and without the change to `web.config` suggested by Haney, with no difference in outcome. I'm now waiting for a production error to be thrown again, but I'm not anticipating any change. The plot thickens.

Comment: To the downvoter: An explanation would help me better understand what you didn't like about the question.

Comment: What happens when you use your debugger? Is `OnErrorSignaled` getting hit? Have you stepped through it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to trigger an exception manually in this system so that I can use a debugger. The site works fine for me when I run it on my local machine.

Comment: In your code somewhere just use `throw new Exception();` should trigger it.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET, adding modules via `web.config` requires a specific Type format of `"Class, Assembly"`. For your case, it is currently:

```
<add name="ErrorLog" type="HRCommittee.ErrorLogModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
```

It needs to be this:

```
<add name="ErrorLog" type="HRCommittee.ErrorLogModule, HRCommittee" preCondition="managedHandler" />
```

Replace `HRCommittee` with whatever the assembly that's being compiled is actually named.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to make a difference either way. However, see my update to the OP for additional information I've learned.

Answer (score 0):

While implementing your own module can be a valid solution, I think that it is much simpler to just use [error filtering](https://elmah.github.io/a/error-filtering/) to modify each error before sending it to ELMAH.

In your `Global.asax.cs` file include code like this:

```cs
void ErrorLog_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs args)
{
    var httpContext = args.Context as HttpContext;
    if (httpContext != null)
    {
        var error = new Error(args.Exception, httpContext);
        
        // TODO: iterate over server variables, etc. in the error object to remove sensitive data

        ErrorLog.GetDefault(httpContext).Log(error);
        args.Dismiss();
    }
}
```

What the code basically does it to dismiss all errors logged to ELMAH but create a new one where you are in better control of what is being logged.

Source: https://blog.elmah.io/enrich-elmah-errors-using-error-filtering-hook/

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. One challenge, though.  `ErrorLog.GetDefault(httpContext).Log(error)` logs the error to the database, but doesn't email it. I can't find an equivalent that sends email. That's how the existing code works. But this doesn't change what gets emailed.

Comment: Oh I see. What if you use `ErrorSignal.FromContext(httpContext).Raise(error);` instead of the `Log` call?